# Perl iterate through each match

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I'm scanning through a page of raw html looking for this regex. (The quote mark on the end is intentional).

```
m/(https?:\/\/.*?(?:'|"))/
```

This pattern is likely to match ~ 100 times. What is a common perl idiom/a quick way to iterate through a list of all capture group matches?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) (a very fine tutorial)

```
while ($x =~ /(\w+)/g) {
    print "Word is $1, ends at position ", pos $x, "\n";
}
```

You can use `while` together with the `g` modifier to iterate over all matches, with `$1` you get the content of your capturing group 1, and in this example from the tutorial you get also the position with `pos`.

Comment: Thanks stema for recommanding perlretut: it is an awesome page for Regular Expressions in Perl; it covers everything from beginner to advanced.

Comment: Don't forget to add 'm' modifier if you deal with multi-line strings and anchors ^,$

Answer (score 10):

The global matching '`g`' modifier returns a list of captured matches in list context:

```
say $_ for $str =~ /un($wanted)/g;    # Prints only $wanted
```

Answer (score 3):

@Zaid: I think your approach is more compact. hope the following snippet will help to understand your example

```
my $str = 'file_%date%_%name%_%lang%.txt';
my @ts = $str =~ /%([\w]+)%/g;#           <----------Zaid said
print join(", ", @ts);
```

Output:

```
date, name, lang
```