# perl Match multiline pattern in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a program which reads a file line by line and gets data when a pattern is matched.
currently it extracts patterns like
`function abc (int a, int b)`
but i have some functions like
`function xyz (int a, \n

int b)`
which it doesn't match due to file being read line by line.

Is it possible to read the file in some better way or should i use the obvious technique of getting multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to read multiple lines in at once. If the file isn't too large you can just slurp the entire file in (e.g. http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/11/21/slurp.html) and then use a single line regex (use the s option e.g. /stuff.next line/s).

*edit*Example for multiple matches*
The g option allows you to get all the matches. One sample usage is in a while loop, where each time you evaluate the regex you get the next match.
See [Perl iterate through each match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580129/perl-iterate-through-each-match) for more details and examples.

```
while($string=~/(regex)/g){
    DoSomething($1);
}
```

*edit fixed error*

Comment: ok so if i run my regex on the entire file wont it return only the first match each time i run it, or am i missing something?

Comment: You can use your regex in a loop with the g option to get all matches. I'll edit my answer to add an example.

Comment: Whats the best way to do the same if it was a large file?

Comment: @Anand You're better off creating your own question instead of commenting on other people's, you'll get much more visibility.
Also, there are multiple approaches depending on your requirements.