# Perl loop within regex match

Tags: regex, loops, perl

Take a look at this command:

```
perl -0777ne 'print "$&\n\n" while /"(QueryString|Params)":\[(\{"Name":".*?", ?"Value":".*?"\},? ?)*\]/g;' myfile.json
```

It [iterate through each match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580129/perl-iterate-through-each-match) of json strings like:

```json
{
    "Some": "Random stuff",
    "QueryString": [
       { "Name": "IsOrdered",    "Value": "1"              },
       { "Name": "TimeStamp",    "Value": "11654116426247" }
    ],
    "Params": [
       { "Name": "ClassName",    "Value": "PRODUCT"        },
       { "Name": "ListID",       "Value": "Products"       },
       { "Name": "Mode ",        "Value": "1"              },
       { "Name": "Dept"  ,       "Value": "5"              },
       { "Name": "HasPrevOrder", "Value": ""               }
    ],
    "And": {
        "QueryString":[]
    },
    "More": "like",
    "More+": "this"
}
```

Now my question is how to iterate through each regex match of the Name/Value pairs, and join them together back to normal http query string?

For .e.g, For

```
"QueryString":[{"Name":"IsOrdered", "Value":"1"}, {"Name":"TimeStamp", "Value":"11654116426247"}]
```

the joined output should be

```
"QueryString":"IsOrdered=1&TimeStamp=11654116363378"
```

and `"QueryString":[]` to `"QueryString":""`

Note that I want to do regex match & replace because I need the rest of the JSON components be preserved. The JSON file I'm talking about is actually a [har](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) file. It's quit a complicated structure, yet

`"(QueryString|Params)":\[(\{"Name":".*?", ?"Value":".*?"\},? ?)*\]`

is all that I want to replace. Nothing more.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse JSON but a proper Perl module like `JSON` : https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON

Comment: The _"using regex to parse JSON"_ part is done. See the command that I posted. That's not the focus of my question, _unless_ it is a built-in module without the need of installation, even for Alpine or FreeBSD, and it solves my question perfectly.

Comment: The core one is `JSON::PP`, though you really should be using one of the higher performance ones from CPAN. (I like [`JSON::MaybeXS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS))

Comment: No, performance is not my consideration, readily available across all default Perl installation, including Alpine or FreeBSD, or even Oracle env under Windows, is the most important consideration to me.

Comment: Re "*The "using regex to parse JSON" part is done*", not remotely so.

Comment: As far as for my specific case, it is 100% complete @ikegami. Nothing more to cover.

Comment: Re "*It's quit a complicated structure, yet [...] is all that I want to replace. Nothing more.*", All the more reason to AVOID a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `jq`.

```bash
jq '
   walk(
      if type == "object" then
         (
            ( .QueryString, .Params ) | select( . != null )
         ) |= (
            map( @uri "\( .Name )=\( .Value )" ) | join("&")
         )
      else
         .
      end
   )
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/okwSdW3eOXS) on jqplay

This modifies all object with elements with one of those keys. I usually prefer something more targeted (not just for efficiency reasons, but to avoid accidentally changing something that shouldn't be changed), but I don't have enough knowledge of the HAR format to do this.

---

The following is a Perl program that would also achieve the task:

```perl
use feature qw( say );

use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( decode_json encode_json );
use URI::Escape      qw( uri_escape_utf8 );

sub transform {
   for ( @_ ) {
      $_ =
         join "&",
            map {
               join "=",
                  map uri_escape_utf8( $_ ),
                     $_->@{qw( Name Value )}
            }
               @$_;
   }
}

sub fix {
   my $x = shift;
   my $type = ref( $x );
   if ( $type eq "HASH" ) {
      for my $k ( keys( %$x ) ) {
         for my $v ( $x->{ $k } ) {
            if ( $k eq "QueryString" || $k eq "Params" ) {
               transform( $v );
            } else {
               fix( $v );
            }
         }
      }
   }
   elsif ( $type eq "ARRAY" ) {
      fix( $_ ) for @$x;
   }
}

local $/;
while ( <> ) {
   my $data = decode_json( $_ );
   fix( $data );
   say( encode_json( $data ) );
}
```

Comment: will/can the rest of the JSON components be preserved? The JSON file I'm talking about is actually a [har](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) file.

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Comment: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)`. Such case has been dealt with by my carefully constructed regexp in my OP.

Comment: First of all, your solution doesn't work, so that's not true. Secondly, this error is on you. You still haven't provided a representative data sample. I showed what data I used, and it's up to you to adjust for your actual data.

Comment: Adjusted the programs to modify all objects, not just the root object.

Comment: Thanks, here is how I tested it https://jqplay.org/s/JSnT3bqKL5b, with a sample JSON.